# SSL Step Wise Beginners Implementation Guide

Tags: php, ssl, wamp, implementation

I have a fair idea of SSL after a reading from a few places. But from where can a self learned PHP developer learn how to implememnt SSL - IS THERE A STEP WISE GUIDE ?

Specific doubt - The SSL certificate would be a Text File, An Installable App, An XML ?? What

How can one make his own SSL certificate, is there a STEP WISE GUIDE ? (this can be parked for now if this falls on the advanced side.

I have read that code is agnostic to SSL encryption. The Secured Session is established by the server when the HTTPS protocol is called with web pages needing only secure access being kept in a particular folder.

but lets say I purchased an SSL certificate (from Verisign, GoDaddy or whoever), and I need the folowing page accessed over SSL, How would I go about it and what should I do.

```
<?php
echo " This was not changed for sure ! " ;
?>
```

I know I should not SSL Secure all pages since (en)decryption eats into performance. I just need an very basic implementation example for now. Performance tips can be learned later.

Answer (score 1):

So as I see it you want to create a certificate if so the following links might be helpful (you're using LAMP right?) : [1](http://slacksite.com/apache/certificate.php) [2](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/kb/secure/external-ssl) [3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self). WAMP related guides: [1](http://www.viduka.info/eblog/kebic/how-to-setup-https-ssl-on-wamp.html) [2](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986)

Comment: Wamp...but i am going to be impkementing it..so i wanna learn it thw way it helps me do in in the live enviorment

Comment: Oh I see, I've edited the answer to include links relevant to WAMP, hope it helps you.